# Prove to show that 2 different size matrices cannot be added together,without literally try to add them together?

Tags: matrices

Is there any specific counter-example or prove to show that 2 different size matrices  cannot be added together?I know that there will be extra digits with no "pairs" to be added,but just asking if there is any prove available,without trying to add the matrices together.Thank you!

Comment: You don't need a proof. This is impossible by definition of addition of matrices.

Comment: Is there a proof that you cannot add the number 7 to a potato?

Comment: @vadim123 wait. You can't ?

Comment: @KittyL sincerely thank you very much! You answer my question straight to no,which releasing my stress haha

Comment: Can we create a "top troll" badge just to award @vadim123?

Answer (score 4):

In science, you have to distinguish between logical arguments that require proof and definitions. In your case, you are asking to prove a 'definition'. Definitions are not provable arguments, that is not to say they can be formed wrongly.

By definition from [Wikipedia Matrix Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition):

> Regular "matrix addition is the operation of adding two matrices by adding the
>   corresponding entries together. However, there are other operations
>   which could also be considered as a kind of addition for matrices, the
>   direct sum and the Kronecker sum."

**Direct Sum** and **Kronecker sum** operations relax the size equality constraint and do not require matrices to be of the same size - Please see the same link above for more detail.

Note: I have added the word 'Regular' to the standard definition to remove possible ambiguity with other types of addition.